# Deploying and managing Java EE applications on remote machine

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, deployment, jetty, remote-server

I have a VPS machine running Ubuntu 12.04 and I want to deploy and run my local Eclipse projects (mostly wicket projects) on this machine. I installed and started Jetty server on it but could not figure out what to do next. Should I just copy my project files to the /webapps folder and edit configurations? I can sense it is not that easy (Consider me as a noob). Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Generate a war and copy it to webapps folder. Then startup server.

If you need further details, take a look at this:

http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Deploy_Web_Applications